# Expect Script Crash After exp_close and exp_wait

Tags: bash, crash, automation, tcl, expect

My goal is to determine the IP address of the TACACS servers these hosts use to authenticate.

When I ran my script, Unix ops complained that a (process?) table was filling up with "defunct".

I thought, from research online, that "exp_close" and "exp_wait" would eliminate that. I added those lines.

If I recall correctly, ssh worked, but where the script fell back to telnet (as that is all the remote device allowed), the script crashed.

Please help me get the Syntax right so that, regardless of whether SSH/telnet is used, the script runs well; thanks!

(PS. Telnet was my bosses choice, not mine; and he's not currently open to change)

```
spawn ssh -q $USER@$line

    set ssh_id $spawn_id

expect {

eof      {spawn telnet -l $USER $line}

}

expect {
eof      {continue}
}

expect {
-re "\[Uu]sername"  {send "$USER\r"}
}

expect {

"(yes/no)"  { send "yes\r";exp_continue}
}   

expect -re  "\[Pp]assword:" {send "$pass\r"}
expect      "#"


send        "show run | include ip tacacs source-interface\r"
expect      "#"
send        "exit\r"

exp_close -i $ssh_id
exp_wait -i  $ssh_id
             }
exit 0
log_file
```

Comment: What is the error you getting? Sharing the output would be better.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that the failure to close the PTY used for ssh when switching to using telnet might cause a few issues, especially if running lots of instances of this script in parallel. Thus, you'd change:

```
spawn ssh -q $USER@$line

    set ssh_id $spawn_id

expect {

eof      {spawn telnet -l $USER $line}

}
```

To this:

```
spawn ssh -q $USER@$line
set ssh_id $spawn_id

expect {
    eof {
        # Free up resources
        close
        wait
        # Start up the alternative
        spawn telnet -l $USER $line
        # Save it's ID (in a now-poorly-named variable)
        set ssh_id $spawn_id
    }
}
```

Apart from that, this is strange:

```
expect {
eof      {continue}
}
```

I would not expect it to be a good idea unless in a loop. And even then it wouldn't be a good idea as it wouldn't be cleaning up the PTY in that case. You don't include the loop, so I don't know if that's the problem.

Finally, this part is also odd:

```
expect {
-re "\[Uu]sername"  {send "$USER\r"}
}

expect {

"(yes/no)"  { send "yes\r";exp_continue}
}   

expect -re  "\[Pp]assword:" {send "$pass\r"}
expect      "#"
```

You're supplying the username directly, so the first `expect` clause of this little sequence ought to be unnecessary. Secondly, there's no real reason to use `exp_continue` with a single clause unless you intend to wait for a timeout (which quits out of the `expect` by default). It's probably better to rewrite all this as this:

```
expect {
    "(yes/no)"          { send "yes\r";   exp_continue }
    -re "\[Pp]assword:" { send "$pass\r"; exp_continue }
    "#"                 { list }
}
```

If you have to have the username entering in there (why??) then that becomes just another clause in the expect. The `list` command with no arguments effectively does nothing as its result is always the empty string (which is the empty list too).

And there's no point in writing `log_file` after `exit`. It won't be reached; `exit` has no result as it makes the process exit…

Comment: If I was rewriting this from scratch, I'd create a procedure which encapsulates everything _except_ the loop(s) and the fallback to telnet, and make sure that that procedure gets the cleanup right. Then I'd use that procedure to do the core of the work and handle the fallback/looping in the caller of that. It would be much easier to make it work without leaking resources, as it would separate the levels of concerns more completely.

Comment: Donal, thank you so much for taking the time to review my code and offer your feedback, much appreciated.

Comment: spawn ssh -q D2014@10.1.1.1
spawn_id: spawn id exp7 not open
    while executing
"close"
    invoked from within
"expect {
    eof {
        # Free up resources
        close
        wait
        # Start up the alternative
        spawn telnet -l $USER $line
     ..."
    ("foreach" body line 6)
    invoked from within
"foreach line $TACACS_CLIENT {

spawn ssh -q $USER@$line
set ssh_id $spawn_id

expect {
    eof {
        # Free up resources
        close
        wai..."
    (file "./TACACS_LOOPBACK_IDENTIFICATION_EXPERIMENT.sh" line 18)
What did I do wrong here with your fix....?

Comment: foreach line $TACACS_CLIENT {

spawn ssh -q $USER@$line
set ssh_id $spawn_id

expect {
    eof {
        # Free up resources
        close
        wait
        # Start up the alternative
        spawn telnet -l $USER $line
        # Save it's ID
        set ssh_id $spawn_id
    }
}

expect  "ALS1"
send  "enable\r"
expect  "Password:"
send  "password\r"
expect  "#"
send  "show run | include tacacs-server host\r"
expect  "#"
send  "exit\r"

exp_close -i $ssh_id
exp_wait -i $ssh_id
}
exit 0

Comment: Donal, i did a "ps -ef | grep defunct" and instead of seeing the entries increse for either telnet or ssh, i saw neither - even while my script continued to run.                                                                          foreach line $TACACS_CLIENT {

spawn ssh $line

expect {
eof {wait; spawn telnet $line}
}

expect  "ALS1>"
send  "enable\r"
expect  "Password:"
send  "password\r"
expect  "#"
send  "show run | include tacacs-server host\r"
expect  "#"
send  "exit\r"
close
wait
}
exit 0

Comment: @dave PTYs aren't the same thing as processes, and the comment system here doesn't make this practical to debug; I can't tell what is input and what is output…